# find places using language Portuguese Brazil not work

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Find places using  language Portuguese Brazil not work, only in english =/.

Using:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=----&sensor=false&language=pt-BR

Example:

```
var request = {
  location: results[0].geometry.location,
  radius: '500',
  types: [localType]
};
```

localtype in Portugues Brazil not working, only english.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for?

Comment: This doesn't work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/k7N7f/

Comment: Example: 
        var request = {
          location: results[0].geometry.location,
          radius: '500',
          types: 'pharmacy'
        }; 

localtype in Portugues Brazil not work, only english.

Comment: Is `localtype` a variable? Can you please provide an example.